# Retrieve String from res/drawable

Tags: android, string, drawable

I have taken following array; to fill-up gallery:

```
private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
            R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
            R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.ten, R.drawable.elevan,
            R.drawable.twelve, R.drawable.thirteen, R.drawable.fouteen,
            R.drawable.fifteen, R.drawable.sixteen
    };
```

and then I am using click event of gallery:

```
coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View v, int position,
         long rowID) {
             String s = mImageIds[position].toString();
             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), s , 1000).show();
         }
         });
```

but here Toast gives me integer number **2130837507**;

If I take only **mImageIds[position]** in Toast

then it displays path **res/drawable-mdpi/image_name.jpg**, but actually it is not string.
And I want to retrieve String (image_name) from it.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do a toString on the number you get back.  If you want a string from the resource Id as the title of your question suggests, do this:

```
getResources().getString(mImageIds[position]);
```

However, it seems like you want the image name, though that's not what the title of your question is.  If that's the case, this should work:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(mImageIds[position]);
```